# How can I check if the username begins with a letter? JAVASCRIPT - without regex expression

Tags: javascript

how can i check if the username entered starts with a letter **without** using a regex? i would like to use the isLetter function, so how would i go about doing that?

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <script type = "text/javascript">
         var BR = "<br />";
         var username = "";
         var letter1 = ""
         letter1 = username.substr(0,1);
         accepted = 0;
         document.write("Enter a username that has the following:" + BR);
         document.write("The username must have at least 8 characters." + BR);
         document.write("The username must must begin with a letter." + BR);
         document.write("The username must must have one digit." + BR);
         try {
             username = prompt("Please enter a username that follows these rules:");
             if (username.length >= 8) {
                 throw("This length is in range");
             }
             else {
                 throw("This length is not in range"); 
             }
         } 
         catch (x) {
             if (x == "This length is in range") {
                 document.write("This length is in range");
                 accepted = 0;
             }
             else if (x =="This length is not in range") {
                 document.write("The length is not in range.");
                 accepted = 1;
             }
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's for an assignment and we cannot use them because we have not learned them yet.

Comment: You should try to figure this one out, the teacher isn't trying to teach you how to get around without RegEx, but develop your logic.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if(isNaN(str[0])){
  alert('true');
}
```

Just replace str[0] with username[0] or something similar

Comment: What if `str[0] == "#"` or anything else than a letter (including `undefined` if `str.length == 0`) ?

Comment: Well, it's up to her to solve, I just gave her very basic idea how to start. I'm just simply stating the idea that there are a lot of ways that you can think of to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
function isLetter (str) {
    var c = str.charCodeAt(0);
    if ( ((c >= 65) && (c <= 90)) || ((c >= 97) && (c <= 122)) ) {
        alert("It's a letter!!!");
    }
    else {
        alert("It's not a letter!!!");
    }
}
```